# Como criar um filtro personalizado na lestview do android que busque palavras depois do caractere espaço

Tags: listview, hashmap, android-adapter

Nesse código o filtro esta funcionando até a primeira palavra. A partir do momento em que digito o caractere espaço o filtro para de funcionar. 
Exemplo: Pesquisar "Steve Jobs", o sistema se perde. Agora se pesquisar só até "Steve" ele retorna certo.

```
ArrayList<> dados = new ArrayList<>();

SQLiteDatabase db1 = base.getReadableDatabase();

  Cursor c = db1.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE pcodgrupo LIKE '2' ORDER BY pcodprod ",null);

   while (c.moveToNext())
      {
          HashMap map = new HashMap();
          map.put("pcodprod", c.getString(0));
          map.put("pdescricao", c.getString(2));
          map.put("compl", c.getString(5));
          map.put("pprecovenda", c.getString(9));
          map.put("plocalizacaoprod", c.getString(25));
          map.put("pprecoprazo", c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("pprecoprazo")));
          dados.add(map);
      }

String[] from = new String[]{"pcodprod", "plocalizacaoprod", "pdescricao", "compl", "pprecovenda","pprecoprazo"};

 int layout = R.layout.list_teste_item2;

 int[] to = new int[]{R.id.id, R.id.localP, R.id.nome, R.id.comple, R.id.prevoAv, R.id.precoPrazo};

ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView2);

adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, dados, layout, from, to);
lv.setAdapter(adapter);


 edtPesquisa.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
 @Override
 public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
}
 @Override
 public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
     adapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString().trim());
 }
 @Override
 public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

O `SimpleAdapter` não suporta alguns filtors, mude para um `ArrayAdapter` ou utilize um adaptador customizado, [esse por exemplo](https://github.com/slezica/blogActivity/blob/master/src/com/slezica/tools/widget/FilterableAdapter.java) implementa `Filterable`, então permite uma boa quantidade de filtros.

Comment: Obrigado Lucas pelas dicas. Por acaso não teria algum exemplo de Filterable  porque com ArrayAdapter tentei e deu erro no codigo.   Segue abaixo meu código:  adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter <ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>>(this, layout, to, dados);
          lv.setAdapter(adapter1);

Comment: @xvesdeveloper no link que deixei tem um custom Array que implementa Filterable, ele tem licença MIT, então creio que você possa adicionar ele como dependência do seu projeto e usar. Ou abra e veja como foi feito